# Showing page when submit form via ajax - Jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery Mobile for creating mobile application and i have index.html in this html page i have 2 pages(search_form, search_result). I want to submit search form from search_form page and then it should shows the search_result page. The following is my js code:

```
            var formURL = "http://10.0.2.2/jobs/mobile/home/searchJobs/";

            $.ajax(
            {
                url : formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data : $("#search_frm").serialize(),
                //data : "&data=90",
                beforeSend: function() {
                    showLoader();
                },
                success:function(result)
                {   
                    var list = '';
                    var data = $.parseJSON(result);
                    //$("#ulListview1").html($.parseJSON(result)); 
                    $.each(data,function(i,item){

                        if(item.id=='0')
                        {
                            list += "<li><span style='color:red;'>Record not found!</span></li>";
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            list += "<li><a data-transition='slide' href='#job_details_page' onclick='getJobDetails("+item.id+");'>" + item.job_title +"<p style='display:inline;'> at "+item.company+"</p><br><p><span><strong>Expiring On:</strong> "+item.expire_date+"</span> <br><span><strong>Job Location:</strong> "+item.location+"</span></p>"+"</a></li>"; 
                        }
                      //alert(data[i]["id"] + " " + data[i]["username"]);  
                    });
                    //hide loader
                    hideLoader();

                    $("#search_list").html(list); 
                    $("#search_list").listview("refresh");
                    $("#search_result").css("display","block");

                },
                error: function(jqXHR,status)
                {
                    alert(status);
                    //alert($.parseJSON(jqXHR));     
                }
            });
```

Could you please help to fix this problem?

Comment: hello, what's the error are you experiencing?

Comment: No error, just i want to show the search_result page but i dont know how

Comment: to change the page to the results add ($( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#search_result", { transition: "slide" });) after ($("#search_result").css("display","block");) or even better at the last line of the whole function